# My program can't output the lines correctly

Tags: c, algorithm, stdio

I'm relatively new in C and I currently reading Kernighan's book.
One of the problems in the book is to create an algorithm that from a input line output the line if it is more than 10 characters long.

The point is I'm frustrated because I cant find what is wrong with my code. I debugged and recreate it many times but still cant find out what's going on!

The escape character from function `getl()` is '.' (dot), and sometimes works and other times don't. If you compile it and test you will see:

```sh
gcc -Wall -o out 'script.c'
```

The question header from the book is:

> “Exercise 1-17. Write a program to print all input lines that are longer than 10 characters.”

I'm sure that's relatively easy, but I really wanted to know why this algorithm is not working as expected, i think it has something to do with '\n'.

If someone could help me find out what's the problem with the code, I would appreciate it.

#### Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10000

int getl(char line[], int lim) {
    char c;
    int count;

    for (count = 0 ; count < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != '.' ; count++) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            line[count] = '\n';
            count++;
            break;
        }
        line[count] = c;
    }
    line[count] = '\0';
    return count;
}
    
int main() {
    char line[MAX];
    int len = 1;

    for (; len > 0 ;) {
        getl(line, MAX);
        len = getl(line, MAX);
        if (len >= 10)
            printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a valiant attempt.  But typing "." doesn't escape anything, it merely behaves like \n.  You could call exit() for example.  Or break out of the main() for-loop when the string equals "quit".

Comment: Once you have this working, you should rethink the exercise. One of the goals of the exercise is to think about how to solve problems without storing a lot of data unnecessarily or imposing an arbitrary limit such as 10000. Hint: It is fairly simple to write a program that does not print lines with 10 or fewer characters but does print lines of **any** longer length. How many characters do you need to be able to store to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the threshold is 10 characters? It is 80 in my copy of the second edition of K&R (and exercise 1-17 in the first edition is something completely different).

Comment: Hey, i edited the question for not need to writing 80 characters all the time tested the program, also thanks for the advice

Comment: You only check the condition in the for loop,  so it  finctions like a whlile loop. Maybe change this for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

Your code almost works. You just seem to have some repeated lines here and there that confuse things.

Specifically, you are calling `getl(line, MAX);` twice in a row. The first gets the input, but don't save the count, the second has only an empty stdin buffer to work with so no sensible count is saved from that. Removing the first call that don't save the count fixes your issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10000

int getl(char line[], int lim) {
    char c = getchar();
    int count;
    
    for (count = 0 ; c != '.' ; count++) {
        line[count] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    line[count++] = '\n';
    return count;
}
    
int main() {
    char line[MAX];
    int len = 1;
    for (; len > 0 ;) {
        len = getl(line, MAX);
        if (len >= 10)
            printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I cant believe i miss that

Answer (score 0):

First, you're calling your getl function twice instead of once (you only want to read lines one by one). Fixing that should work.
Then I think you shouldn't add the trailing '\n' to your lines, just print it when your line is longer than 10 characters, in your code, the '\n' will be counted as a character.

Here's the modified code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int getl(char line[])
{
    char    c;
    int     count;

    for (count = 0; count < MAX - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '.' ; count++)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        line[count] = c;
    }
    line[count] = '\0';
    return (count);
}

int main()
{
    char    line[MAX];
    int     len = 1;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        len = getl(line);
        if (len >= 10)
            printf("%s, c = %i\n", line, len);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. https://ideone.com/cXXRUH

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10000

int getline_length(char line[]) {
  char ch;
  int count = 0;

  printf("\nWaiting for INPUT...");
  // Using clear while loop to get input, removing redundent complexity 
  // Either `.` or `\n` consider End Of Line 
  while(count < MAX-1 && ((ch = getchar()) != '.' || (ch = getchar()) != '\n')) {
      line[count++]=ch;
  }
  line[count] = '\0';
  return count;
}

int main() {
   char line[MAX];

   while(1) {
       // reset array before each input 
       memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
       int len = getline_length(line); //No need to pass limit 
       if (len >= 10) {
           printf("%s", line);
        } else {
            printf("len < 10");
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standard. Microsoft Windows defines it as an extension, but that is not suitable for answering a K&R exercise. And flushing the input is unnecessary in this exercise.